# Generating FittedModels from vector-valued linear model fits

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I have vector-valued data with normally distributed noise that I want to analyse. Assumptions on data can be made; in this specific example, it's expected that components of fitted vector values always have a unit sum.

Here's a toy example of manually finding a fit with these constraints:

```
With[{source = {x^2 / 2, 1 - x^2 / 2 - x, x}},
 With[{
   coeff = {a, b, c, d, e, f},
   eqn =
    {a x^2 + b x + c, d x^2 + e x + f, 
     1 - (a x^2 + b x + c) - (d x^2 + e x + f)},
   data = 
    Table[{x, 
      source + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1], 3]}, {x, 0, 1, .025}]},
  Sum[SquaredEuclideanDistance[v[[2]], eqn /. x -> v[[1]]], {v, data}] //
     eqn /. Last@Minimize[# /. Abs -> Identity, coeff, Reals] & // Echo //
   Show[
    ListPlot[
     Transpose[{{#1, #2[[1]]}, {#1, #2[[2]]}, {#1, #2[[3]]}} & @@@ data]],
    Plot[Join[source, #], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]] &]]
```

> {-0.0162628+0.0842304 x+0.43683 x^2,0.99686 -0.908144 x-0.608563 x^2,0.0194033 +0.823914 x+0.171733 x^2}

[image]

Now I have a curve fit for each vector component, but what I would really want is corresponding `FittedModel` objects with `"MeanPredictionBands"` and such properties. Is there any way to cross this gap, practically creating a model with the above fitting polynomial as `"BestFit"`?

**EDIT**: Looking at `InputForm` of `FittedModel` objects would suggest this is feasible. Most of the arguments seem straight-forward, although some on the end of the definition are not that obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87927/fit-model-with-two-dependent-variables.

Comment: The potential downside to the possible duplicate is that one would need to be able to assume that the error variances are the same for all 3 equations.  If that's not a feasible assumption for real-world data, then using `LogLikelihood` and `FindMaximum` functions would allow for potentially unequal variances.

Comment: The answer I gave below is wrong if the triplets of observations sum exactly to 1 as opposed to just the expected values summing to one.  If the former, then by definition the 3 observations are correlated with each other and that doesn't yet seem to be addressed by either of the two current answers.  (The estimates of the coefficients won't change much - if at all - but the estimates of the standard errors of the coefficients and the predictions will be off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you know how to put this altogether from scratch, I suspect that some will not be able to construct the confidence or prediction bands reliably in such a manner.  If it is a reasonable assumption that the error variances are the same for all models, then just modifying the input data is about all that's necessary to get the desired output from `NonlinearModelFit`.  (I make too many mistakes so I need to go that route.)

First, include in some dummy variables in the data:

```
(* Sample data using dummy variables:
1,0,0 => data from model 1
0,1,0 => data from model 2
0,0,1 => data from model 3 *)
data={{1, 0, 0, 0., -0.0988754}, {0, 1, 0, 0., 0.936639}, {0, 0, 1, 0., -0.168444}, {1, 0, 0, 0.025, -0.0201999}, {0, 1, 0, 0.025, 1.02862}, {0, 0, 1, 0.025, -0.0562009}, {1, 0, 0, 0.05, -0.0120367}, {0, 1, 0, 0.05, 0.870238}, {0, 0, 1, 0.05, -0.0936423}, {1, 0, 0, 0.075, -0.128804}, {0, 1, 0, 0.075, 0.985538}, {0, 0, 1, 0.075, 0.125768}, {1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.078006}, {0, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.775311}, {0, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.0928273}, {1, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.121525}, {0, 1, 0, 0.125, 0.71475}, {0, 0, 1, 0.125, 0.0477607}, {1, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.115014}, {0, 1, 0, 0.15, 0.851672}, {0, 0, 1, 0.15, 0.0933949}, {1, 0, 0, 0.175, -0.0260633}, {0, 1, 0, 0.175, 0.721085}, {0, 0, 1, 0.175, 0.2533}, {1, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.0929319}, {0, 1, 0, 0.2, 0.741054}, {0, 0, 1, 0.2, 0.246308}, {1, 0, 0, 0.225, -0.121485}, {0, 1, 0, 0.225, 0.558944}, {0, 0, 1, 0.225, 0.180121}, {1, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.196925}, {0, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.739204}, {0, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.216802}, {1, 0, 0, 0.275, 0.00288085}, {0, 1, 0, 0.275, 0.531013}, {0, 0, 1, 0.275, 0.364702}, {1, 0, 0, 0.3, -0.0748257}, {0, 1, 0, 0.3, 0.452435}, {0, 0, 1, 0.3, 0.246644}, {1, 0, 0, 0.325, -0.102033}, {0, 1, 0, 0.325, 0.552273}, {0, 0, 1, 0.325, 0.307822}, {1, 0, 0, 0.35, 0.012419}, {0, 1, 0, 0.35, 0.493619}, {0, 0, 1, 0.35, 0.109975}, {1, 0, 0, 0.375, 0.174347}, {0, 1, 0, 0.375, 0.403849}, {0, 0, 1, 0.375, 0.640423}, {1, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.0267628}, {0, 1, 0, 0.4, 0.50906}, {0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.249802}, {1, 0, 0, 0.425, 0.145036}, {0, 1, 0, 0.425, 0.401913}, {0, 0, 1, 0.425, 0.365026}, {1, 0, 0, 0.45, 0.0917381}, {0, 1, 0, 0.45, 0.452611}, {0, 0, 1, 0.45, 0.191856}, {1, 0, 0, 0.475, 0.05115}, {0, 1, 0, 0.475, 0.461663}, {0, 0, 1, 0.475, 0.370011}, {1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.275475}, {0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.20153}, {0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.479379}, {1, 0, 0, 0.525, 0.184857}, {0, 1, 0, 0.525, 0.26697}, {0, 0, 1, 0.525, 0.586871}, {1, 0, 0, 0.55, 0.236133}, {0, 1, 0, 0.55, 0.379411}, {0, 0, 1, 0.55, 0.61064}, {1, 0, 0, 0.575, 0.241561}, {0, 1, 0, 0.575, 0.243509}, {0, 0, 1, 0.575, 0.508213}, {1, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.220454}, {0, 1, 0, 0.6, 0.118133}, {0, 0, 1, 0.6, 0.595092}, {1, 0, 0, 0.625, 0.12719}, {0, 1, 0, 0.625, 0.126479}, {0, 0, 1, 0.625, 0.644849}, {1, 0, 0, 0.65, 0.114451}, {0, 1, 0, 0.65, 0.144761}, {0, 0, 1, 0.65, 0.581061}, {1, 0, 0, 0.675, 0.197143}, {0, 1, 0, 0.675, 0.186537}, {0, 0, 1, 0.675, 0.705692}, {1, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.231923}, {0, 1, 0, 0.7, -0.0542245}, {0, 0, 1, 0.7, 0.939961}, {1, 0, 0, 0.725, 0.318287}, {0, 1, 0, 0.725, 0.0657639}, {0, 0, 1, 0.725, 0.609313}, {1, 0, 0, 0.75, 0.177536}, {0, 1, 0, 0.75, 0.0269016}, {0, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.741112}, {1, 0, 0, 0.775, 0.357059}, {0, 1, 0, 0.775, -0.191036}, {0, 0, 1, 0.775, 0.830267}, {1, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.188352}, {0, 1, 0, 0.8, -0.0579005}, {0, 0, 1, 0.8, 0.695232}, {1, 0, 0, 0.825, 0.271996}, {0, 1, 0, 0.825, -0.304167}, {0, 0, 1, 0.825, 0.832492}, {1, 0, 0, 0.85, 0.408437}, {0, 1, 0, 0.85, -0.0930686}, {0, 0, 1, 0.85, 0.717563}, {1, 0, 0, 0.875, 0.570663}, {0, 1, 0, 0.875, -0.286103}, {0, 0, 1, 0.875, 0.96456}, {1, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.340535}, {0, 1, 0, 0.9, -0.25579}, {0, 0, 1, 0.9, 0.672478}, {1, 0, 0, 0.925, 0.0811443}, {0, 1, 0, 0.925, -0.332707}, {0, 0, 1, 0.925, 0.841893}, {1, 0, 0, 0.95, 0.327199}, {0, 1, 0, 0.95, -0.43617}, {0, 0, 1, 0.95, 0.849182}, {1, 0, 0, 0.975, 0.359762}, {0, 1, 0, 0.975, -0.67714}, {0, 0, 1, 0.975, 0.950295}, {1, 0, 0, 1., 0.494625}, {0, 1, 0, 1., -0.533217}, {0, 0, 1, 1., 1.09384}};

(* Define equation using dummy variables *)
eqn[m1_, m2_, m3_, x_, a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] :=
 {m1, m2, m3}.{a x^2 + b x + c, d x^2 + e x + f, 
   1 - (a x^2 + b x + c) - (d x^2 + e x + f)}

(* Run regression *)
coeff = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, eqn[m1, m2, m3, x, a, b, c, d, e, f], 
   coeff, {m1, m2, m3, x}];

(* Get mean prediction bands *)
mpb1 = nlm["MeanPredictionBands"] /. {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 0, m3 -> 0};
mpb2 = nlm["MeanPredictionBands"] /. {m1 -> 0, m2 -> 1, m3 -> 0};
mpb3 = nlm["MeanPredictionBands"] /. {m1 -> 0, m2 -> 0, m3 -> 1};

(* Show data, fit, and mean prediction bands *)
Show[ListPlot[data[[All, {4, 5}]]],
 Plot[{nlm[1, 0, 0, x], nlm[0, 1, 0, x], nlm[0, 0, 1, x]}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}],
 Plot[{mpb1, mpb2, mpb3}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Red, Red, Green, Green}]]
```

[image: Data, fit, and mean prediction bands]

And this works even if the model is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

I dug a bit into `FittedModel` and it would seem pretty straight-forward to reconstruct `FittedModel`s for simple linear model fits of one-dimensional data. As a result, I created a `PreFittedLinearModel` function which takes data, fitted polynomial (plus options, such as `Weights`) as input, and returns a `FittedModel` object as a result:

```
ClearAll@PreFittedLinearModel;

Options[PreFittedLinearModel] = 
  FilterRules[Options[LinearModelFit], 
   ConfidenceLevel | Tolerance | VarianceEstimatorFunction | Weights |
     WorkingPrecision];

PreFittedLinearModel[data_, poly_, var_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{funs = Table[var^i, {i, 0, Exponent[poly, var]}]},
  FittedModel @@ {
    {"Linear", N@CoefficientList[poly, var], {{var}, funs}, {0, 0}},
    {N[OptionValue[Weights] /. Automatic -> Table[1, Length@data]]}, 
    data, Table[N@funs, {var, data[[All, 1]]}], 
    Function[Null, Internal`LocalizedBlock[{var}, #], {HoldAll}], 
    Sequence @@ (# -> OptionValue[#] & /@ {ConfidenceLevel, Tolerance,
         VarianceEstimatorFunction, WorkingPrecision})}]
```

Now I can check how (95%) confidence intervals compare with my original function:

```
With[{source = {x^2/2, 1 - x^2/2 - x, x}},
 With[{
    coeff = {a, b, c, d, e, f},
    eqn = {
      a x^2 + b x + c, d x^2 + e x + f, 
      1 - (a x^2 + b x + c) - (d x^2 + e x + f)},
    data = 
     Table[{x, 
       source + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1], 3]}, {x, 0, 1, .025}]},
   Sum[SquaredEuclideanDistance[v[[2]], eqn /. x -> v[[1]]], {v, data}] //
     eqn /. Last@Minimize[# /. Abs -> Identity, coeff, Reals] & //
     PreFittedLinearModel[{#1, #2[[3]]} & @@@ data, #[[3]], x] &] //
   Plot[Join[{x}, #["MeanPredictionBands"]], {x, 0, 1}, 
    Evaluated -> True] &]
```

[image]

... but, as @JimB stated, this approach has issues in its core.

**EDIT**: Probably I should modify this to work with any linear combination of functions, and extract polynomial coefficient functions for this generalized version instead of assuming a polynomial. Polynomials just happened to be the tool I used originally...